# Why does my convolutional model does not learn?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on building a CNN for sound classification. The problem is relatively simple: I need my model to detect whether there is human speech on an audio record. I made a train / test set containing records of 3 seconds on which there is human speech (speech) or not (no_speech). From these 3 seconds fragments I get a mel-spectrogram of dimension 128 x 128 that is used to feed the model.

Since it is a simple binary problem I thought the a CNN would easily detect human speech but I may have been too cocky. However, it seems that after 1 or 2 epoch the model doesn’t learn anymore, i.e. the loss doesn’t decrease as if the weights do not update and the number of correct prediction stays roughly the same. I tried to play with the hyperparameters but the problem is still the same. I tried a learning rate of 0.1, 0.01 … until 1e-7. I also tried to use a more complex model but the same occur.

Then I thought it could be due to the script itself but I cannot find anything wrong: the loss is computed, the gradients are then computed with `backward()` and the weights should be updated. I would be glad you could have a quick look at the script and let me know what could go wrong! If you have other ideas of why this problem may occur I would also be glad to receive some advice on how to best train my CNN.

I based the script on the LunaTrainingApp from “Deep learning in PyTorch” by Stevens as I found the script to be elegant. Of course I modified it to match my problem, I added a way to compute the precision and recall and some other custom metrics such as the % of correct predictions.

Here is the script:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import argparse
import numpy as np

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from torch.optim import SGD
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

from dataset_loader.audiodataset import AudioDataset
from models.vadnet import VADNet
from utils.earlystopping import EarlyStopping


class VADTrainingApp:
    
    def __init__(self, sys_argv=None):
        
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        
        parser.add_argument("--train_path",
                           help='Path to the training set',
                           required=True,
                           type=str,
        )
        
        parser.add_argument("--test_path",
                           help='Path to the testing set',
                           required=True,
                           type=str,
        )
        
        parser.add_argument("--save_path",
                           help='Path to saving the model',
                           required=True,
                           type=str,
        )
        
        parser.add_argument("--save_es",
            help='Save the checkpoints of early stopping call',
            default="checkpoint.pt",
            type=str,
        )
        
        parser.add_argument('--num-workers',
            help='Number of worker processes for background data loading',
            default=8,
            type=int,
        )
        
        parser.add_argument("--batch_size",
                            help='Batch size to use for training',
                            default=32,
                            type=int,)
        
        parser.add_argument('--epochs',
            help='Number of epochs to train for',
            default=50,
            type=int,
        )
        
        parser.add_argument('--lr',
            help='Learning rate for th stochastic gradient descent',
            default=0.001,
            type=float,
        )
        
        self.cli_args = parser.parse_args(sys_argv)
        
        # related to the hardware
        self.use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if self.use_cuda else "cpu")
        
        # directly related to the neural network
        self.model = self.initModel()
        self.optimizer = self.initOptimizer()
        
        # For early stopping
        self.patience = 7
        
        # For metrics
        self.METRICS_LABELS_NDX = 0
        self.METRICS_PREDS_NDX = 1
        self.METRICS_LOSS_NDX = 2
        self.METRICS_SIZE = 3
        
    def initModel(self):
        """Initialize the model, if GPU available computation done there"""       
        model = VADNet()
        model = model.double()
        
        if self.use_cuda:
            log.info("Using CUDA; {} devices".format(torch.cuda.device_count()))
            if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
                model = nn.DataParallel(model)
            model = model.to(self.device)
        return model
               
    def initOptimizer(self):
        
        return SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr=self.cli_args.lr)#, momentum=0.8, weight_decay=0.01)
    
    def adjust_learning_rate(self):
        """Sets the learning rate to the initial LR decayed by a factor of 10 every 20 epochs"""
        self.cli_args.lr = self.cli_args.lr * (0.1 ** (self.cli_args.epochs // 20))
        for param_group in self.optimizer.param_groups:
            param_group['lr'] = self.cli_args.lr
    
    def initTrainDL(self):
        
        trainingset = AudioDataset(self.cli_args.train_path, 
                                   n_fft=1024, 
                                   hop_length=376, 
                                   n_mels=128)
        
        batch_size = self.cli_args.batch_size
        if self.use_cuda:
            batch_size *= torch.cuda.device_count()
               
        trainLoader = DataLoader(trainingset,
                                batch_size = batch_size, 
                                shuffle=True, 
                                num_workers=self.cli_args.num_workers,
                                pin_memory=self.use_cuda)
        return trainLoader
    
    def initTestDL(self):
        
        testset = AudioDataset(self.cli_args.test_path, 
                                   n_fft=1024, 
                                   hop_length=376, 
                                   n_mels=128)
        
        batch_size = self.cli_args.batch_size
        if self.use_cuda:
            batch_size *= torch.cuda.device_count()
               
        testLoader = DataLoader(testset,
                                batch_size = batch_size, 
                                shuffle=True, 
                                num_workers=self.cli_args.num_workers,
                                pin_memory=self.use_cuda)
        return testLoader
    
    def main(self):
        
        log.info("Start training, {}".format(self.cli_args))
        
        train_dl = self.initTrainDL()
        test_dl = self.initTestDL()
        
        trn_writer = SummaryWriter(log_dir='runs' + '-trn')
        val_writer = SummaryWriter(log_dir='runs' + '-val')
        
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=self.patience, path=self.cli_args.save_es, verbose=True)

        for epoch_ndx in range(1, self.cli_args.epochs + 1):
            log.info("Epoch {} / {}".format(epoch_ndx, self.cli_args.epochs))
            
            # Adjust the new learning rate
            self.adjust_learning_rate()
            
            # Train the model's parameters
            metrics_t = self.do_training(train_dl)
            self.logMetrics(metrics_t, trn_writer, epoch_ndx)

            # Test the model
            metrics_v = self.do_val(test_dl, val_writer)
            self.logMetrics(metrics_v, val_writer, epoch_ndx, train=False)
            
            # Add the mean loss of the val for the epoch
            early_stopping(metrics_v[self.METRICS_LOSS_NDX].mean(), self.model)

            if early_stopping.early_stop:
                print("Early stopping")
                break
        
        # Save the model once all epochs have been completed
        torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), self.cli_args.save_path)
        
    def do_training(self, train_dl):
        """Training loop"""
        self.model.train()
        
        # Initiate a 3 dimension tensor to store loss, labels and prediction
        trn_metrics = torch.zeros(self.METRICS_SIZE, len(train_dl.dataset), device=self.device)
        
        for batch_ndx, batch_tup in enumerate(train_dl):

            if batch_ndx%100==0:
                log.info("TRAINING --> Batch {} / {}".format(batch_ndx, len(train_dl)))
            
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            
            loss = self.ComputeBatchLoss(batch_ndx, 
                                        batch_tup, 
                                        self.cli_args.batch_size,
                                        trn_metrics)

            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()
            
        return trn_metrics.to('cpu')
    
    def do_val(self, test_dl, early_stop):
        """Validation loop"""
        with torch.no_grad(): 
            self.model.eval()
            
            val_metrics = torch.zeros(self.METRICS_SIZE, len(test_dl.dataset), device=self.device)
                
            for batch_ndx, batch_tup in enumerate(test_dl):
                
                if batch_ndx%100==0:
                    log.info("VAL --> Batch {} / {}".format(batch_ndx, len(test_dl)))
                    
                loss = self.ComputeBatchLoss(batch_ndx, 
                                            batch_tup, 
                                            self.cli_args.batch_size,
                                            val_metrics)
                
        return val_metrics.to('cpu')  
       
    def ComputeBatchLoss(self, batch_ndx, batch_tup, batch_size, metrics_mat):
        """
        Return a tensor the loss of the batch
        """

        imgs, labels = batch_tup
        imgs = imgs.to(device=self.device, non_blocking=True)
        labels = labels.to(device=self.device, non_blocking=True)  
        
        outputs = self.model(imgs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)

        loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="none")
        loss = loss_func(outputs, labels)

        start_ndx = batch_ndx * self.cli_args.batch_size
        end_ndx = start_ndx + labels.size(0)

        metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LABELS_NDX, start_ndx:end_ndx] = labels.detach()
        metrics_mat[self.METRICS_PREDS_NDX, start_ndx:end_ndx] = predicted.detach()
        metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LOSS_NDX, start_ndx:end_ndx] = loss.detach()
            
        return loss.mean()
        
    def logMetrics(self, metrics_mat, writer, epoch_ndx, train=True):
        """
        Function to compute custom metrics: accurracy and recall for both classes
        and % of correct predictions. Log the metrics in a tensorboard writer
        """ 
        
        # Confusion matrix to compute precision / recall for each class
        tn, fp, fn, tp = torch.tensor(confusion_matrix(metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LABELS_NDX], 
                                                       metrics_mat[self.METRICS_PREDS_NDX], 
                                                       labels=[0,1]).ravel())
        
        precision_no_speech = tp / (tp + fp)
        recall_no_speech = tp / (tp + fn)
        
        # class speech is labelled 0, so true positive = true negative for speech
        precision_speech = tn / (tn + fn)
        recall_speech = tn / (fp + tn)
        
        # % of correct predictions - optional metrics that are nice
        no_speech_count = (metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LABELS_NDX] == 0).sum()
        speech_count = (metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LABELS_NDX] == 1).sum()
            
        no_speech_correct = ((metrics_mat[self.METRICS_PREDS_NDX] == 0) & (metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LABELS_NDX] == 0)).sum()
        speech_correct = ((metrics_mat[self.METRICS_PREDS_NDX] == 1) & (metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LABELS_NDX] == 1)).sum()
            
        correct_all = (speech_correct + no_speech_correct) / float(speech_count + no_speech_count) * 100
        correct_speech = speech_correct / float(speech_count) * 100
        correct_no_speech = no_speech_correct / float(no_speech_count) * 100
        
        loss = metrics_mat[self.METRICS_LOSS_NDX].mean()
        
        writer.add_scalar("loss", loss, epoch_ndx)
        
        writer.add_scalar("precision/no_speech", precision_no_speech, epoch_ndx)
        writer.add_scalar("recall/no_speech", recall_no_speech, epoch_ndx)
        writer.add_scalar("precision/speech", precision_speech, epoch_ndx)
        writer.add_scalar("recall/speech", recall_speech, epoch_ndx)
        
        writer.add_scalar("correct/all", correct_all, epoch_ndx)
        writer.add_scalar("correct/speech", correct_speech, epoch_ndx)
        writer.add_scalar("correct/no_speech", correct_no_speech, epoch_ndx)
        
        if train:
            log.info("[TRAINING] loss: {}, correct/all: {}% , correct/speech: {}%, correct/no_speech: {}%".format(loss, 
                                                   correct_all,
                                                   correct_speech,
                                                   correct_no_speech))                    
        else:
            log.info("[VAL] loss: {}, correct/all: {}% , correct/speech: {}%, correct/no_speech: {}%".format(loss, 
                                                   correct_all,
                                                   correct_speech,
                                                   correct_no_speech))  
                     
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    VADTrainingApp().main()
```

Regarding the model I am using a simple CNN:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math

class VADNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=1, conv_channels=8):
        super().__init__()

        self.tail_batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm2d(1)

        self.block1 = ConvBlock(in_channels, conv_channels)
        self.block2 = ConvBlock(conv_channels, conv_channels * 2)
        self.block3 = ConvBlock(conv_channels * 2, conv_channels * 4)
        self.block4 = ConvBlock(conv_channels * 4, conv_channels * 8)

        self.head_linear = nn.Linear(8 * 8 * conv_channels * 8, 2)

        self._init_weights()

    def _init_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if type(m) in {
                nn.Linear,
                nn.Conv3d,
                nn.Conv2d,
                nn.ConvTranspose2d,
                nn.ConvTranspose3d,
            }:
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(
                    m.weight.data, a=0, mode='fan_out', nonlinearity='relu',
                )
                if m.bias is not None:
                    fan_in, fan_out = \
                        nn.init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(m.weight.data)
                    bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_out)
                    nn.init.normal_(m.bias, -bound, bound)

    def forward(self, input_batch):
        bn_output = self.tail_batchnorm(input_batch)

        block_out = self.block1(bn_output)
        block_out = self.block2(block_out)
        block_out = self.block3(block_out)
        block_out = self.block4(block_out)

        conv_flat = block_out.view(block_out.size(0),-1)
        linear_output = self.head_linear(conv_flat)

        return linear_output


class ConvBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, conv_channels):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels, conv_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=True,
        )
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            conv_channels, conv_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=True,
        )
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

    def forward(self, input_batch):
        block_out = self.conv1(input_batch)
        block_out = self.relu1(block_out)
        block_out = self.conv2(block_out)
        block_out = self.relu2(block_out)

        return self.maxpool(block_out)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are applying 2D 3x3 convolutions to spectrograms.

Read it once more and let it sink.
Do you understand now what is the problem?

> A convolution layer learns a *static*/*fixed* local patterns and tries to match it *everywhere* in the input. This is very cool and handy for images where you want to be [equivariant](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16060/37752) to translation and where all pixels have the same "meaning".
>  However, in spectrograms, different locations have different meanings - pixels at the top part of the spectrograms mean high frequencies while the lower indicates low frequencies.
>  Therefore, if you have matched some local pattern to a local region in the spectrogram, it may mean a completely different thing if it is matched to the upper or lower part of the spectrogram.
>  You need a different kind of model to process spectrograms. Maybe convert the spectrogram to a 1D signal with 128 channels (frequencies) and apply 1D convolutions to it?

Comment: As I saw some models use a 2D convolution, for instance the VGGish model. The rational being that my audio record can be represented as a 2D output: X axis = time, Y axis = Frequencies and the pixel values represent the amplitude. See for instance:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/audioset/vggish/vggish_slim.py

Comment: @Ben that's correct, but you do not have "translation equivariance" on the y axis

Comment: Okay then I will change the model architecture! Thank you very much for your insight and your help!